# Laravel form only saving last in array

Tags: laravel-5

Right now I have a chat and what I am working on is being able to take selected chat messages and turn them into a post with comments.  My struggle is that right now I am only getting the very last comment to save and none of the comments before it.  This has to do with not being able to write the foreach loop correctly when saving in the controller I believe.

The error I am getting right now is

```
 Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
```

I am showing the commenters array but not saving it correctly.  The commentors are ids of users involved and the user_id (not userId) is what I need to save for both, right now only getting '11' and not '9'.  as you can see from the error message

```
  ...'commenters' => '  9,  11, ', 'user_id' => '11', 'comment' => 'hey there'), 'userId' => '9', 'commentorIds' => array(), 'createPost' => object(Post)))
```

Form

```
<div class="selectedChatSection" style="padding: 15px 15px 15px 15px;">
  {!! Form::open(['url'=>'post/selectedChatPost']) !!}
    <div class="jumbotron">
      <center><img src="/img/icons/icon-chat.png"></center>
    </div>
  @foreach ($postSavers as $postSaver)
      <div class="postSaverId" data-id="{{$postSaver->id}}"></div>
  @endforeach
    <input type="hidden" name="space-id" value="">
    <input type="hidden" multiple="multiple" name="commenters" value="@foreach($selectedChats as $selectedChat){{$selectedChat->id}},   @endforeach ">
  @foreach ($selectedChats as $selectedChat)
    <div style="border-top: 1px solid #eee;padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;">
    <p><img src="/assets/avatars/{{$selectedChat->avatar}}" height:"75" width="75" style="border-radius:50px;">&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="{{$selectedChat->id}}">{{$selectedChat->name}}&nbsp;&nbsp;:&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="hidden" name="comment" value="{{$selectedChat->body}}">{{$selectedChat->body}}</p>
  @endforeach 
</div>

<div class="modal-footer">
  {!! Form::submit('post', ['id'=> 'post-button']) !!}
  {!! Form::close() !!} 
</div>
```

Controller

```
    public function storeSelectedChat() {
    $input = Request::all();
    $userId = Auth::user()->id;
    $commentorIds = array();

    $createPost = new Post;
    $createPost->space_id = 8;
    $createPost->user_id = $userId;
    // $createPost->content = $input['content'];
    $createPost->linkPhoto = "/img/icons/icon-chat.png";    
    $createPost->save();

    //needs to be a foreach loop here for each comment/chat segment.

        foreach(Input::get('commenters') as $commenter) {
            $createComments = new Comment();        
            $createComments->post_id = $createPost->id;
            $createComments->comment = $input['comment'];
            $createComments->user_id = $commenter;
            $createComments->save();
        }
    }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  I have done this before but nothing seems to work in this instance for some reason.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `<input type="hidden" multiple="multiple" name="commenters" value="@foreach($selectedChats as $selectedChat){{$selectedChat->id}},   @endforeach ">` should not have multiple attribute.

> The multiple attribute works with the following input types: email,
>   and file.

According to http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_multiple.asp. Even though the multiple attribute logically makes sense to you because logically you have multiple commentors, semantically it is incorrect. You still have one `<input>` attribute and what it contains logically is up to you interpret. You should use regex to separate your comma delimited input and then use `foreach` on that resulting array.